# Laravel 5 API: update record error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, api-design

So I am working an a Laravel 5.2 API and I am working on creating the update method on a specific Model. The index, show($id) and store methods work fine so far. However I am getting the following error on my update method implementation:

```
BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 81:
Method save does not exist.
```

Here is the update method:

```
public function update($id, CreateZoneRequest $request)
{
    $zones = Zone::where('_id', '=', $id) -> get();

    if(sizeof($zones) == 0){
        return response()->json(['message' =>'That zone number is invalid', 'code' => 404], 404);
    }

    $description = $request->get('description');

    $zones ->description = $description;

    $zones ->save();

    return response() -> json(['message' => 'The zone has been updated'], 200);
}
```

Here is the CreateZoneRequest code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class CreateZoneRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return 
        [
            'description' => 'required',
        ];
    }

    public function response (array $errors){
        return response() -> json(['message' => 'You are missing a required field', 'code' => 422], 422);
    }
}
```

Here is the index method (for reference). This one is working without problems:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

use App\Zone;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

use App\Http\Requests\CreateZoneRequest;

class ZoneController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $zones = Zone::all();

        if(sizeof($zones) == 0){
            return response()->json(['message' =>'There are no zones', 'code' => 404], 404);
        }

        return response() -> json(['data' => $zones], 200);
    }
```

Here is the detailed Error Message when trying to use PUT on this endpoint api/v1/zones/1?description=Blah

[image: Method save does not exist.]

Comment: Use `$zones = Zone::where('_id', '=', $id) ->first();` or `$zones = Zone::find($id);` instead of `get` otherwise you'll be getting "arrays" back,

Comment: $zones ->description = $request->description;   prettier way for replacing these lines..  $description = $request->get('description');
$zones ->description = $description;

Comment: @apokryfos if I use that I now get an error in the SQL query: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' which is weird since I am telling the where clause to use _id

Comment: @WiloMaldonado Which one causes that error? The `find` or the `first` ?

Comment: Both Actually. But I'm wondering if the problem is the find or first? Or if the problem is actually when it is trying to save?

Comment: The Zone model is defined correctly but seems to be defaulting to using the id as the primary key. But the model is defined as $primarykey = '_id'; protected $table = 'Zone';

Comment: WOW. The error was simple.... I was using $primarykey instead of $primaryKey... damn camel case... sorry people

Answer (score 2):

When you use `get()` method you get a `Collection` object. You should use `first()` method to get model object.

Read more here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#retrieving-single-models

Comment: That seems to be the solution however, the first() method seems to assume that the primarykey of that table is id. But in my case it's _id. I have defined that properly in the Zone Model as:         protected $primarykey = '_id';
     protected $table = 'Zone';

Comment: @WiloMaldonado if you defined primarykey I don't see a problem when you try to use `first()`. Try it and say here or edit your question when you get error.

Comment: I found the error. I was using $primarykey instead of $primaryKey... It's Monday lol

Answer (score 1):

You have to get a single instance of Zone model using first(), then you can use save() or update() methods

```
public function update($id, CreateZoneRequest $request)
{
    $zones = Zone::where('_id', '=', $id) -> first();

    if(sizeof($zones) == 0){
        return response()->json(['message' =>'That zone number is invalid', 'code' => 404], 404);
    }

    $description = $request->get('description');

    $zones ->description = $description;

    $zones ->save();

    return response() -> json(['message' => 'The zone has been updated'], 200);
}
```

Comment: That makes sense. However, Now I am getting this error from the SQL query:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: update `Zone` set `description` = Blah where `id` is null)

because the primary key of that table is not id but _id. However, the where clause is specific when getting the Zone.

What do you suggest>

Comment: It seems like your primary key is `_id` instead of traditional `id`? Have you set it in your model like protected $primaryKey = '_id'; ?

Comment: Yes.        
 protected $primarykey = '_id';
     protected $table = 'Zone';
     public $timestamps = false;
     protected $fillable = array('description');

Comment: Is `$id` variable gets passed correctly to `update ` function? Try to output it, and which row causes last error? They one with `save()` method?

Comment: I found the error. I was using $primarykey instead of $primaryKey ... damn Camel Case

Comment: Indeed. It's Monday haha